# Multi level UITableView for iPhone Application

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am in a situation where i need nth level `UITableView`.

My problem is i have a list of accounts, when user tap on account I need to show list of its sub accounts, in sub accounts list if user tap on a sub account I need to show list of its sub accounts and so on.

Comment: so use recursion and add childviewcontrollers until you hit the end of the line. whats the question here?

Comment: childviewcontrollers for every level?

Comment: As i have written in my question, i have nth level recursion, so how to handle childviewcontrollers in this scenario?

Comment: If I understand you right you want to present all these child table views in the table cells of the respective parent table view. Let me tell you - don't! Cascading table views leads to quite some tricky UI behavior, and is also getting confusing quite fast. Why don't you present the subtables in a new screen (e.g. with UINavigationController)?

Comment: download the code from here http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Listings/Classes_SectionHeaderView_m.html might it helps you

Comment: @Manohar its only 2 level code, i need truly nth-level depth

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is create a subclass of UITableViewController that will recreate instances of itself when the user selects a row. put the first instance in a navigationcontroller and use

```
[navigationController pushViewController: animated]
```

to display the children. added benefit: you will get a navigationbar to go in reverse direction for free. thats not recursive strictly speaking, but its close and it will do the job. Just make sure you have a conditional statment in there somewhere, so it wont go on forever.

Answer (score 1):

What you need can be easily achieved using the free Sensible TableView framework. The framework will automatically display your list of accounts, and will generate all the needed detail views once an account cell is tapped.